# Preventing Windows program from interpreting ^Z as end of file

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

My job is to translate a application from C -> C++ that have been installed on a linux distribution.so I wish the functionallity of C and linux.

I have a problem with reading binary file. It says that it reaches the EOF when it encounters a `ctrl-Z` character before it has reached the actual end of the file.

#### Precious execution in bash

```
zcat file.txt.gz | txtToBinary | binaryToOutput
```

#### Execution in command prompt

```
txtToBinary.exe < file.txt | binaryToOutput.exe
```

#### Raw text file

```
 R  5643BYIDK           DK0016060346 11DKKXKLY 160               1
 R 10669VJK 98 1        IS0000004018  4ISKXICE 240         5000000
 M814
```

#### txtToBinary.exe - Sample Output:

```
^@^@^@ hello ^@    ^Z^@^@^@^@
^@^@^[SWMA ^Y^YC
```

The problem is that the program interprets the first `^Z` as the end of file.

## Tried so far

My solutions has been to do the following when compiling on windows using **c++**

#### Execution in command prompt

```
txtToBinary.exe < file.txt | binaryToOutput.exe
```

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv []){
    int loop (args_t* args){

    for (;;){
        char data [1024];
        int temp = read_msg (data, sizeof (data));
}

int read_msg(void* data, int size){
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    _setmode(0,_0_BINARY);
    if(fread(((unsigned char *)data)+sizeof(*hdr),hdr->size-sizeof (*hdr),1,stdin) != 1);
        if(feof(stdin))
             printf("End of file error\n");
}
```

I have also tried [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) which some of the answers have me. But that also failed.

## StackOverflow Answers

When looking at answer here in SO, we see [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034012/ifstream-eof-end-of-file-is-reached-before-the-real-end), [Windows EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258812/why-does-this-stream-of-data-end-at-byte-26), [Binary solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307057/how-to-read-a-binary-file-in-c-video-images-or-text),[Binary Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268591/using-c-standard-streams-in-binary-mode-through-swig-python-on-mingw) and [Stream data end at byte 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258812/why-does-this-stream-of-data-end-at-byte-26?lq=1) and [Reaching EOF early Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164002/why-is-fread-reaching-the-eof-early?rq=1). They tell me that:

**- Windows keys (CTRL + Z, ^Z) makes an end of file**

**- I have to read in binary format**

Comment: Did you open the file with `fopen(filename, "rb")`? If not, do so.

Comment: 'Reaches end of file before it has reached the end of the file' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Wintermute Well the program takes the file as input, as seen above. Which I would like to keep. I am experimenting with opening the file like that, but that decrease the flexibility of the program

Comment: Oh, right. Does `freopen(NULL, "rb", stdin)` work?

Comment: @Wintermute Sadly no, Visual Studio or Windows in general will not let me use NULL for freopen.

Comment: Hum. I tried a few things, and Windows behaves strangely. After `_setmode(0, _O_BINARY);`, `fread` handles `\x1a` characters correctly, as does `read`. However, `getchar`, `getc`, and `fgetc` still give `EOF` for them, and it turns out they even do that for file streams that are opened with `"rb"`. Are you certain your problem is with the `fread` call, or do you use other read operations that could run into this sort of problem?

Comment: Wow, okay. Thanks, it still does not make sense for me though. Thank you for the help @Wintermute. I have extended my code so one can see what exactly happens from the beginning of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It had to do with where you read from. You need to put

_setmode(0,_0_BINARY);

in the main() function!!!!!!!! Remember this, otherwise other reads or writes will not be included.

Answer (score 1):

fread() is part of stdio.  What you're doing is opening the raw file as binary, but then doing text-mode standard I/O.

You could replace your existing fread() call with the read() system call.  (That is, fread() is a library call that does some buffering, ultimately to call through to read().)